# Inkscape shortcuts like Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape, shortcuts

I want to find an **Inkscape** shortcuts profile with defined **Illustrator** shortcuts. For example **'A'** for *Node Selecting* tool, **'P'** for *Pen* not *Pencil*. Please give a link to file to Import from *Edit > Preferences > Interface > Keyboard Shortcuts*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [wiki post](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Customizing_Inkscape), one can use Inkscape built-in shortcuts to configure for Illustrator. I fired up my Inkscape to investigate and found this result:

[image: inkscape keyboard shortcuts]

Also directly from the above wiki, which includes a link to the git repository:

> You can find a list of the available keymaps either in the Inkscape
>   preferences, in the dropdown, or in the Inkscape git repository.